# Cannot resolve "import as" situation ("AttributeError module x has no attribute y")

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I have a project with the following structure:

```
project/
    driver.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        core/
            util.py
            common.py
            __init__.py
```

---

```
# project/driver.py

import lib.core.common as abc
pass
```

---

```
# project/lib/core/__init__.py

from .util import Worker
```

---

```
# project/lib/core/util.py

import lib.core.common as abc

class Worker:
    pass
```

---

```
# project/lib/core/common.py

def stuff():
    pass
```

Now when I run `python3 driver.py` (from project's directory), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.core.common as abc
  File "/home/user/project/lib/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .util import Worker
  File "/home/user/project/lib/core/util.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.core.common as abc
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'core'
```

This happens **only** when both conditions are met:

1. When I do `import lib.core.common as abc` instead of `import lib.core.common`.
2. When the `project/lib/core/__init__.py` contains `from .util import Worker` import.

The thing is that I would like to keep the `import lib.core.common as abc` import form.

Could anybody explain what's going on here, please?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but your problem would go away if you didn't do the eager `from .util import Worker` in `lib/core/__init__.py`. Basically, you have a dependency cycle: `lib.core.common -> lib.core.__init__ -> lib.core.util.Worker -> lib.core.common`. While `Worker` is being defined, the `common` module won't really exist yet. Why do you need to pull `Worker` into the package scope like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have circular dependent imports. you try to execute

```
import lib.core.common as abc
```

in two files, in `driver.py` and in `util.py`

The easiest way to fix this is to move the path import to the end of the node module, [some docs](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm),
or

```
def dostuff():
    from foo import bar
    ...
```

or this also will work,

```
from lib.core import common as abc
```

When Python imports a module, it checks the module registry to see if the module was already imported. If the module was already registered, Python uses that existing object from cache. The module registry is a table of modules that have been initialized and indexed by module name. This table can be accessed through `sys.modules`.

If it was not registered, Python finds the module, initializes it if necessary, and executes it in the new module's namespace.

Comment: What do you mean by moving the path import to the end of the node module? Can I ask for an example applied to my case?

Comment: @JoaoAlby i update my answer, you can use `from lib.core import common as abc` in your two files and it will work

Comment: import in middle of the file is against pep8